# Codeblocks Organization - Can you have header and source in the same folder?

Tags: codeblocks

I'm working on a project in CodeBlocks and am being inconvenienced by the project tree.

Let's say I have two C files: foo.c and foo.h. These files live in physical memory within the FooFolder directory.

When I import the FooFolder into a CodeBlocks project, the project separates them into a Src folder and Header folder. However, I would rather be able to just have a folder called FooFolder and let foo.c and foo.h live in there as they do in physical memory.

Is there any way to do this in CodeBlocks?

Thanks!

Comment: Can’t check at the moment, but I seem to recall a configuration option such as “separate headers and sources” that is enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the workspace tree-view, right click on **Workspace** and un-check the item **Categorize by file types**